# Trim Video with FFMPEg

Tags: android, android-ffmpeg

In my application, I have the functionality to trim videos.

I am using FFmpeg here.
Below is my code

Declared on top,

```
 FFmpeg ffmpeg;
```

Loading library using the following code,

```
try {

        if (ffmpeg == null) {

            Log.e("loadFFMpegBinary","null");
            ffmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(Constants.appContext);

        }

        ffmpeg.loadBinary(new LoadBinaryResponseHandler() {



            @Override public void onFailure() {

                Log.e("loadBinary","Failure");

            }



            @Override public void onSuccess() {


                Log.e("onSuccess","onSuccess");

            }

        });

    } catch (FFmpegNotSupportedException e) {
        Log.e("FFmpegNot",":-"+e);


    }
```

Trimming Using the following code,

```
File externalStoragePublicDirectory = new File(destPath);
    if (!externalStoragePublicDirectory.exists() ? externalStoragePublicDirectory.mkdir() : true) {

        String filePrefix = yourRealPath.substring(yourRealPath.lastIndexOf("."));
        String destFileName = getString(R.string.app_name) + System.currentTimeMillis();
        boolean isFastMode = false;
        File dest = (filePrefix.equals(".webm") || filePrefix.equals(".mkv")) ? new File(externalStoragePublicDirectory, destFileName + ".mp4") : new File(externalStoragePublicDirectory, destFileName + filePrefix);
        int fileNo = 0;
        while (dest.exists()) {
            fileNo++;
            dest = (filePrefix.equals(".webm") || filePrefix.equals(".mkv")) ? new File(externalStoragePublicDirectory, destFileName + fileNo + ".mp4") : new File(externalStoragePublicDirectory, destFileName + fileNo + filePrefix);
        }
        Log.e(TAG, "startTrim: src: " + yourRealPath);
        Log.e(TAG, "startTrim: dest: " + dest.getAbsolutePath());
        Log.e(TAG, "startTrim: startMs: " + startMs);
        Log.e(TAG, "startTrim: endMs: " + endMs);
        String filePath = dest.getAbsolutePath();

        Log.e(TAG, "startTrim: filePath: " + filePath);


        String[] complexCommand = {"-ss", "" + startMs / 1000, "-y", "-i",
                yourRealPath, "-t", "" + (endMs - startMs) / 1000, "-s",
                "320x240", "-r", "15", "-vcodec", "mpeg4", "-b:v", "2097152",
                "-b:a", "48000", "-ac", "2", "-ar", "22050", dest.getAbsolutePath()};

try {

        ffmpeg.execute(complexCommand, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(String s) {
                Log.e(TAG, "FAILED with output : " + s);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String s) {
                Log.e(TAG, "SUCCESS with output : " + s);

            }

            @Override
            public void onProgress(String s) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Started command : ffmpeg " + command);

            }

            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                Log.e(TAG, "Started command : ffmpeg " + command);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                Log.e(TAG, "Finished command : ffmpeg " + command);


            }
        });
    } catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {
        Log.e("Exception",";-"+e);
    }
```

Here I am getting following error,

> 12-13 12:53:38.057 31029-31029/com.jobsounder E/VideoCropperFragment: FAILED with output : ffmpeg version n3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
>         built with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
>         configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
>         libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
>         libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
>         libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
>         libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
>         libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
>         libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
>         libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
>         libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
>       Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/emulated/0/Download/VID-20181211-WA0008.mp4':
>         Metadata:
>           major_brand     : isom
>           minor_version   : 512
>           compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
>           encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
>           comment         : vid:v0702afc0000beoc8l4hfpit57rr9vbg
>         Duration: 00:00:15.09, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1550 kb/s
>           Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 576x1024, 1478 kb/s, 27.43 fps, 27.43 tbr, 409k tbn, 54.87 tbc (default)
>           Metadata:
>             handler_name    : VideoHandler
>           Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 64 kb/s (default)
>           Metadata:
>             handler_name    : SoundHandler
>       /data/app/com.jobsounder-2/lib/arm/JobSounder1544685817737.mp4: **Permission denied**
>   12-13 12:53:38.057 31029-31029/com.jobsounder E/VideoCropperFragment: Finished command : ffmpeg [Ljava.lang.String;@11c7227b

Comment: `Permission denied` – Are you sure you have permission to read and write those files?

Comment: @MikeM.
I did provide permissions in the manifest,
READ_EXTERNaL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: That's not enough, on newer versions. Since Marshmallow, you have to request dangerous permissions at runtime, too, if your `targetSdkVersion` is 23 or above. For now, to test, you can manually enable your app's permission on its page in the device Settings. Also, `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` implies `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, so you really just need the write permission.

Comment: @MikeM.
Done the stuff bro

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Did you get it working by manually enabling that permission?

Comment: I have written the code to enable permisson, as we write in marshmallow

Comment: Are you certain it's been granted? How are you determining that? Also, since you have both the read and write permissions, are you explicitly requesting `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`? On Oreo and above, you won't the the write permission unless you explicitly request that specific one.

Comment: Sorry, did I misunderstand what you were saying? Did you mean you solved it with the runtime permissions request? Or is it still not working for you?

Comment: @MikeM.
Yes bro
I am not able to solve it
I tried using runtime permissions alos

Comment: Ah, OK. About the only other thing I could suggest to try is open your app's Settings page, go to the Permissions, disable the Storage permission, and then re-enable it. That'll at least let you know if it's an issue with only getting partial Storage permissions.